# kivy FileChooserListView on_selection event not working as expected

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to observe the `selection` property (ObservableList) of a FileChooserListView object by binding `on_selection` to a method that updates a text label.

Based on my interpretation of the kivy documentation I thought the following code would work, but no amount of clicking or double-clicking on filenames causes the label to get updated or the print statement to get executed.  Am I misinterpreting the documentation with respect to `on_<property>` change events?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView


class FCApp(App):
    def build(self):
        my_layout = AppLayout()
        return my_layout


class AppLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.lbl = Label(size_hint_y=0.1, text='Select a file...')
        self.fc = FileChooserListView(size_hint_y=0.9)

        # Bind changes to the file chooser's selection property to a function
        self.fc.bind(on_selection=self.update_label)

        self.add_widget(self.lbl)
        self.add_widget(self.fc)

    def update_label(self, obj):
        print('update_label_called')
        self.lbl.text = str(obj.selection)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FCApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `on_<property>` if you extend the `FileChooserListView`. In that situation you can define a method `on_selection()` as described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-on-propname).

Or you can just use the `Property` name in the binding as:

```
self.fc.bind(selection=self.update_label)
```

as described [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-bind).

Assuming that you just change the binding code, you will need to modify your `update_label()` method:

```
def update_label(self, fc_instance, selection):
    print('update_label_called')
    self.lbl.text = str(selection)
```

Comment: Now that I can grab the list of selected files, is there any hope of representing the items as selected visually? (I have read in other Stack Overflow and kivy GitHub repo issues that multiselect is a problem with the FileChooserListView and the underlying TreeView). If you have had any experience with workarounds to this issue I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: My workaround is to use `FileChooserIconView`.

Comment: Not work for me also partial ...Any suggest ? Only double click trigger on_submit ...